# PCA on data and training with SVM with K-fold CV and Gridsearch

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, pca

I need to train a SVM model using LinearSVC and a 10-fold cross-validation with an internal 2-fold Gridsearch to optimze gamma and C. But I also have to apply PCA on my data to reduce its size.
Should I apply PCA before or within the loop where the CV and training of the model happens?
In the latter case I would have different numbers of Principal Components for each loop, but is there a disadvantage on that?

Comment: Create a pipeline that does `GridSearch{Pipeline[PCA->SVM]}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: You should probably better to post it here : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is not clear why you have an internal 2-fold grid search. For me you should 1/ do PCA, 2/ do  Gridsearch optimzation and 3/ 10-fold cross-validation to get the mesure metric, but the gridsearch may give a good result without this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to create a sklearn `Pipeline` and put both steps (`PCA` and `LinarSvc` within it). This will create an object that implement `fit()` and `predict()` and that can be used within a `GridSearchCV`.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

pipe = Pipeline([('pca', PCA()),
                 ('clf', LinearSVC())])
params = {
    'pca__n_components' : [2, 5, 10, 15],
    'clf__C' : [0.5, 1, 5, 10],
}

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=params)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: So, now I got this: 
```pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("scaler", StandardScaler()), ("pca", PCA()), ("clf", SVC(kernel="rbf"))])  Cs = np.logspace(-4,4,5) gammas = np.logspace(-4,4,5)  params = {"clf__gamma": SVM_model_gammas, "clf__C": SVM_model_Cs}  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)  gridsearch = GridSearchCV(clf, params, scoring="accuracy", iid=True, verbose=1) gridsearch.fit(X_train, y_train)```

but it tells me that "Invalid parameter clf for estimator SVC()"

I apologize for the formatting.

Comment: 'C' paramerter of `SVC` must be stricly positive.